# Forcing axis labels - How to include x,y inputs for a Z matrix to have sensible axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I have a Z matrix and when I plug it into pcolormesh, it works perfectly and gives me the following plot. The only problem is that the axes now displays the matrix indices. The code that I used make it is given below:
[image]

```
#boo - most of the parameters like title,xyz labels, filename comes from command line
data = np.loadtxt((args.data),dtype=float, comments="#")
cmap = plt.get_cmap('bwr')
fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
divnorm = colors.DivergingNorm(vmin=np.amin(data), vcenter=0, vmax=np.amax(data))
im0 = ax0.pcolormesh(data,norm=divnorm, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im0,ax=ax0)
ax0.set_title(str(title))
plt.xlabel(str(xlabel))
plt.ylabel(str(ylabel))
filename = str(prefix) + "."+ str(fileformat)
plt.savefig(filename)
```

I wanted to rescale the x-axis by a factor of 0.1 (ended up doing it manually since I did not see a workaround) and set the y-axis to change with respect to another array (Note that: I'm not manipulating Z matrix instead I'm using a physically meaningful experimental value array - here, sortData - corresponding to matrix indices). I changed my code as follows - x axis and yaxis seem alright but my heatmap looks different. Can someone shine some light on this? Many Thanks

[image]

```
    #foo
    Data = np.loadtxt((args.data),dtype=float, comments="#")
    sort = np.loadtxt((args.sortData),dtype=float, comments="#")

    fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('bwr')
    divnorm = colors.DivergingNorm(vmin=np.amin(Data), vcenter=0, vmax=np.amax(Data))
    #  im0 = ax0.pcolormesh(Data,norm=divnorm, cmap=cmap)
    #  ax0.set_xscale(1, "linear")
    x = np.arange(0.0,10.6,0.1)  # need to set the ticks manually
    y = sort[:,1]
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    Z=z.reshape(len(y),len(x))
   im0 = ax0.pcolormesh(X,Y,Data,norm=divnorm, cmap=cmap)#, extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
   #im0 = ax0.pcolormesh(x,y,Data,norm=divnorm, cmap=cmap)#, extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])

    cbar = fig.colorbar(im0,ax=ax0)

    if args.zlabel !=None:
         cbar.ax.set_ylabel(str(args.zlabel))
    ax0.set_title(str(args.title))
    plt.xlabel(str(args.xlabel))
    plt.ylabel(str(args.ylabel))
    filename = str(args.prefix) + "."+ str(args.fileformat)
    plt.savefig(filename)
```

**EDIT 1:**
When I plot the boo, y-axis is uniformly spaced since we are dealing with the matrix indices. When I plot foo, they are not since the array values corresponding to these indices ( not that of  Data matrix but the external y array that is of same dim as Data but has values stored in it corresponding to expt) are not equally spaced. The problem is The y values corresponding to The first 5 y indexes of Data matrix are 1.32, 3.200, 3.311, 3.38, 3.40 and their x values change throughout the range [xmin to xmax]. But there's a giant blob of red thing between 0 and 5 (Y) that goes horizontally all the way till the end of xlim. Clearly something is wrong but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: what is the shape of the original data array?

Comment: data.shape =  (106,348) . I think I'm only seeing left bottom part of the boo in the second plot but I'm not sure.

Comment: well, it obviously *can* be different. Without `x` and `y` as input, each cell will have the same size, but if `y` is non-uniformly spaced, like `[1, 2, 5,100, 101, 103]` that will of course give a different image.

Comment: What I think it is doing is that it checks for the dimension of y with that of the data matrix and it just substitutes the value from y array. I might be wrong here. Also a side note to @Heike x goes from 0 to 105 and y from 0 to 347 in the boo and same for foo but now x goes from 0 to 10.5 and y goes from ymin to ymax but in 348 steps. I can edit  the question, if this was not obvious. I'm sorry

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, is there a way to accommodate non-uniformly spaced array ?

Comment: pcolormesh can take any array (may it me uniformly spaced, or non-uniformly spaced) as input. The restriction is that it needs to be the shape of z or one more and that it needs to be sorted ascendingly.

Comment: I think I have met this criterion. Otherwise, I should have gotten an error. Clearly there's something wrong in my new code that I'm not seeing.

Comment: My argument is: There does not need to be anything wrong with the code, it may just be that your data is non-uniformly spaced, in which case the picture you get is totally expected.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Let me look at the data and make sure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Just double-checked the data, there's a clear diff between data and plot. The  y values corresponding to The first 5 y indexes of Data matrix are 1.32, 3.200, 3.311, 3.38, 3.40 and their x values change throughout the range [xmin to xmax]. Hence the big blob of red between y [0,5] is wrong.

Comment: The red blob is the range between 1.32 and 3.20 (or beyond, one cannot know without having all data available), so to me this all seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to plot the data in Boo but with some different set of tick labels then I think a modification of the following self-contained example would probably work for you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors

title = 'Foo'
xlabel = 'X'
ylabel = 'Y'


rv = np.random.rand(100)  # uniform random vector
data = rv[:,None] - rv.T  # pairwise diffs

cmap = plt.get_cmap('bwr')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
divnorm = colors.DivergingNorm(vmin=np.amin(data), vcenter=0, vmax=np.amax(data))
im0 = ax.pcolormesh(data, norm=divnorm, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im0, ax=ax)

# do tick labeling stuff here
nticks = 5 
x_tick_pos = np.linspace(0,100,nticks)
y_tick_pos = np.linspace(0,100,nticks)
ax.set_xticks(x_tick_pos)
ax.set_yticks(y_tick_pos)
xtick_labels = [str(x) for x in np.linspace(0, 10, nticks)] # can be any list of strings
ytick_labels = [str(y) for y in np.linspace(0, 10, nticks)] # len must match nticks
ax.set_xticklabels(xtick_labels)
ax.set_yticklabels(ytick_labels)
ax.set_title(title)
plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)

plt.show()
```

Note that if you want to do fancier things, like have the tick labels rotated so that they can be easier to read, you might be aided by checking out the matplotlib tutorial [on labeling heatmaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @LGS, Ideally what I wanted was to arrange the y-axis within y_min and y_max. Say y1 = 1.2 y2=3 y3 = 5 .78 blah blah..So instead of equally spaced horizontal beams, I should have unequally spaced vertical lines - But I wanted equally spaced labels at the same time. Forcing labels was tough and thanks to you I have one less thing to worry.